# Any convenient way to save and share deleted but good answers or entire questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Let's say I have bookmarked an old question, which by current rules is off-topic, but which has great and useful answer, which I'd like to share. Then I notice the question getting deleted, so I can't really share the link to it any more, and those I shared it with can no longer access it themselves.

I can of course save the deleted page, optionally edit it to remove clutter, and then share it as a document file. But this is rather tedious, and also feels somehow... let's say "ideologically wrong" to take creative commons content, and hide it away in my private files. I also don't want to start hosting the content publicly myself.

**Is there a good way to share deleted content to those with no account or too little reputation?**

This is general question, but the specific case which prompted the question is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092382/learning-lua-fast/8097810#8097810).

Comment: That's a nice short tutorial. How about stackprinter: http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=8092382&service=stackoverflow

Comment: @Deduplicator Interesting service, didn't know about that! Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me that from the p.o.v. of site support the answer is the same as has always been given to similar questions "If the site makes it so that you can easily access deleted posts (which is what a "convenient way to save and share deleted [posts]" would entail) then there is little point in *deleting them in the first place*."

Comment: @Louis Deletion of useful content is done in order to keep the site clean and on topic, as far as I understand it. As long as deletion accomplishes that goal, it doesn't matter if deleted information is still accessible to "normal people" too (and not just the freaks with 10k+ reputation). So no, it would not make deletion process pointless.